# How do I add callback validator with addElement in zend form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-validate

I'm trying to create a simple Zend form using `pm_Form_Simple` class. I need a callback validator with its `addElement` method. Here's what I did.

```
$form = new pm_Form_Simple();
$form->addElement('text','my_number',
                 array('label'=>'Your number',
                'validators'=>array(
                                array('name'=>'Callback',false,'
                                options'=>array('messages'=>'Invalid number',
                               'callback'=>function($value,$context=array()){
                                                if($value < 0){ 
                                                     return false;
                                                }else{ 
                                                    return true;
                                                }    
                                         },
                                 ))
                   )));
```

This gives me an error when submitting the form

```
Missing argument 1 for CommonPanel_Validate_Callback::__construct()
```

I have tried this structure also

```
 array(
      new \Zend\Validator\Callback(
      array(
     'messages' => array(\Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Invalid number'),
      'callback' => function($value){
                        if($value < 0){ 
                           return false;
                        }else{ 
                          return true;
                        }  
                    }
   )))
```

This gave me an error `include_once(Zend/Validator/Callback.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I don't see `Zend/Validator` in my zend installation,so I changed it to `zend/Validate`

This time the error was `Class 'Zend\Validate\Callback' not found`

I know there exists `LessThan` & `GreaterThan` validators, but can anyone kindly help/guide me on how to add `callback` validator with `addElement` function ?

Comment: Somehow you are mixing zf1 and zf2. Zend/Validator is in zf2, Zend_Validate in zf1. Download again zf2 and try again with your second approach.

Comment: @Demo, Sorry I'm new to Zend. But let me ask, is my first method is any close to how it should be done in ZF1?